# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful biking resources and websites
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/968).

Comment: I like how adblock is unaware of these.  Accidental feature!

Answer (score 19):

[image: Sheldon Brown's Bicycle Technical Info]

Comment: Shamelessly copied from last year.

Answer (score 13):

[image: A site for bike light reviews, beamshots, technical information, and advice. Created by Stack Exchange Bicycles user nhinkle!]

Comment: This is an incredibly good resource put together by our own nhinkle. I'd love to see this get to the ad rotation.

Comment: @Purr I generally haven't been investing much time into reviewing a wide selection of low-end generic Chinese lights. There are too many nearly-identical options to distinguish between, and with rampant counterfeiting and lack of clear branding, it's hard to say if the light I'm reviewing is even the same light someone might get if they bought from the same product page. By the time you buy a decent battery pack separately, you aren't saving much money compared to a legitimate light from a trustworthy vendor.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss this further, you can ping me in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome

Comment: They should add "Radon" lights, they are essentially budget china lamps BUT their extra cost over budget china lamps pays for a battery pack claimed to be filled with Samsung rechargeable Li batteries. While the batteries do come in an unbranded "made in china box" I am still getting 4h of the claimed 4.5hour run time at 100% after a year and when the pack finally dies I will be cracking it open to check if there are indeed Samsung batteries inside as claimed. Lumens are exaggerated but my 2000lum model gives better illumination than some which measured around 1200lum

Comment: Deleted an earlier comment to which nhinkle replies because what i wrote was unfair.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Park Tool's Repair Help and Education]

Comment: Also shamelessly copied from [last year](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/861/community-promotion-ads-2014). This site (while technically commercial) is probably the second most useful reference online after Sheldon Brown.

Answer (score 5):

[image: View the latest blog posts from the Bicycles Stack Exchange community!]

Comment: Once again, shamelessly copied from last year, though we may want to update the image (it is 2015, after all).

Answer (score 5):

[image: Help us fight bicycle theft—register your bike.]

Comment: This is a really good, free, bike registration system that is really helping people to get their stolen bikes back. Complete with an API, etc.  My graphics skills are not great, so I encourage somebody else to make a better version of a Bike Index ad. :)

Comment: I'm asking around to see if someone with more design xp wants to do another version, if not this is great. Thank you so much @freiheit!

Comment: This is last year's community promotion ads. Not sure why we haven't gotten a new one.

Comment: @Batman: yes, but when they post a new one, it's usually pretty fast for some ads from the prior year to get copied over...

Comment: New community promotion ads thing is up: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/community-promotion-ads-2016 -- need to change size and need to add a 1 pixel border...

Answer (score 3):

[image: OsamAnd: Offline maps/GPS]

Answer (score 2):

[image: @StackBicycles]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: I'm surprised people are downvoting this. I'm not a Twitter user myself, but I'm all for anything that helps grow the community.

Comment: The community is here on stackexchange.  Other places like twitter and facebook etc will simply dilute the community here.

Comment: I'm curious how the twitter account works. As of today there are only 98 followers. I don't see how the link would create an unmanageable amount of congestion, especially if the followers are coming from SE in the first place. #twitter #bicycle #whoupdatesthedamnthing

Answer (score 2):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bicycles.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is a copy of [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12383) - it will change if there are questions with bounties.

Comment: This ad doesn't meet the size requirements.

Comment: @nhinkle: Not a problem; see [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884).

Answer (score -1):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Urban Planning Proposal!]